# How to apply max function for each row in KDB?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I want to ensure all values in column `x` are no smaller than 0.5, so I do:

```
update x:max (x 0.5) from myTable
```

But this gives an error (in [Studio For KDB+](http://code.kx.com/wiki/StudioForKdb+)):

```
An error occurred during execution of the query.
The server sent the response:
type
Studio Hint: Possibly this error refers to wrong type, e.g `a+1
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try using |

```
q)update x|0.5 from myTable
```

Answer (score 3):

It should work. It worked for me. This is the query I used for testing:

```
update x:max(x;0.5) from myTable
```

-- Check semicolon in max function

Comment: Very nice - it hadn't occurred to me that this would work, but it does. Is just as fast as the (admittedly more idiomatic) `x|.5`

Answer (score 1):

Try the [kdb vector conditional](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/q-quirks#caseStatement) its similar to case-when in SQL:

```
q)t:([] a:6?.9)

q)t
a
---------
0.4237094
0.5712045
0.8705158
0.2075746
0.8549775
0.3951729

q)update ?[a<0.5;0.5;a] from t
a
---------
0.5
0.5712045
0.8705158
0.5
0.8549775
0.5
q)
```

Comment: Vector conditional is unnecessary for this simple case, less readable and, on my machine, 4 times slower.